# I want to make href tag dynamic and value will be populated and i have ejs template

Tags: node.js, api, express, server, ejs

Sample code snippet:

index.ejs

```
<p><a href="<%=link%>" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Download</a></p>
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express'); var router = express.Router(); 

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {link:'http://download1588.mediafireuserdownload.com/**c5cq****rb2a/***.jpg'});
});
```

how to get this link as href tag value so that i can download from this link.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is the way you would do that with ejs:

#### index.ejs

`<p><a href="<%= link %>" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Download</a></p>`

#### app.js

```
res.render('index.ejs', { link: "<your link here>" });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Instead we have to use double quote in place of single quote {link: " you link"}

Comment: This is how I used it in my app, and it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way it worked for me.

General example:

```
<a href="somepath/<%= someVariable %>">Read More</a>
```

Example from my project:

```
<a href="/post/<%= post.titleTxt %>">
```