# How to you set the href using the value passed with ejs?

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I am using ejs as my view engine for a node.js express application. I have a profile page which list a users information. On that page I have an href anchor which is a users email address. The value within this tag is set as shown below:

```
<a href=""><%= email%></a>
```

What I would like to do is set the href to be the same value as the contents of the tag, but also when clicked opens the system email app like this:

```
`href="mailto:<%= email%>"`
```

It works as expected if I do something like:

```
<a href="notarealemail@gmail.com"><%= email%></a>
```

Is there a way that I can set the href value like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to make href tag dynamic and value will be populated and i have ejs template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609853/i-want-to-make-href-tag-dynamic-and-value-will-be-populated-and-i-have-ejs-templ)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the href of an anchor tag via javascript!

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="mail-link"><%= email%></a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
let email = <%= email%> 
const mailLink = document.getElementByID('mail-link')
mailLink.href = `mailto: ${email}`
```

I hope this can answer your question!